# C Pointers and strings

Tags: c

When we write `char *str="john";`
No errors will come out but when we write
`int *ptr=50;`
Errors will come out like this
`"Invalid conversion from int to int *".`

Why this difference?
Why do we need to use pointer to store `string`s, while we do not need (can't use) pointers to store `int`s?

Comment: What is there to say?  50 is not a pointer; `"john"` is a pointer.  One is mostly correct (the type should be `const char *`); the other is incorrect.

Comment: Answer yourself: Which types do `50` and `"Hello"` have?

Comment: `Please answer it fast.`.. umm.. how about a DCV instead?

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: 50 in an integer and john is string.

Comment: @user3514850: C does not have a string type.

Comment: It is clear that what OP is asking, still 4 close votes on "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @haccks: Maybe because there is no "RTFM" option?

Comment: Because C doesn't have "strings" like it has integers. It only has char, and pointers to char.

Answer (score 2):

All references refer to ISO 9899:2011 “C11”

The type of a string literal like `"john"` is `char[N]` where `N` is the length of the string (§6.4.5 ¶6). In almost all contexts, an object of array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, type `char*` in this case (§6.3.2.1 ¶3). Assigning an object of type `char*` to an lvalue of type `char*` is legal (§6.5.16.1 ¶1).

The type of a sufficiently small integer literal like `50` is `int` (§6.4.4.1 ¶5). Assigning an object of type `int` to an lvalue of type `int*` is legal as conversion from `int` to `int*` is performed implicitly (§6.5.16.1 ¶1), but your compiler does not conform to the standard and rejects that for some reason.

Comment: A pointer can be converted to an integer and this is very well done implicitly. But the result is implementation defined, not guaranteed to be usable and in far by most use-cases not intended. Thus just a warning instead of an error.

Comment: detail: string literal will be written to a string table in memory and the address gets returned to the pointer.

Comment: @FUZxxl - 6.5.16.1 1 does *not* allow for implicit conversion from `int` to `int *` in an assignment; if the left operand has pointer type, then the right operand must be a *pointer to a compatible type*, a pointer to `void`, or a null pointer constant.  `int *ptr = 50;` is a constraint violation.

Comment: @JohnBode Which paragraph allows this kind of code then? It's so common, I can't believe that's undefined.

Comment: @FUZxxl: it's not *undefined*, it's a constraint violation; a conforming implementation must issue a diagnostic for it (for example, gcc issues the warning "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast).  It's common because people choose to ignore the warning (or turn warnings off).

Answer (score 0):

`"john"` returns a pointer to the first letter of the string constant `john`.

As `char * str` needs a `pointer to char`, the statement `char *str="john";` does not give any warning.

---

But `50` returns the value `50` itself.

`int * p` needs a `pointer to int`, but it gets an `int` `50`. So it gives the warning `Invalid conversion from int to int *`